I am creating a radio streaming scientific articles for third world countries
Tips? I am having problems formatting the text, because it is double column and some have a lot of numbers that may be difficult to parse, I can totally eliminate numbers and other like <>;/[] as well as sites starting with www.
Need more tips for formatting.
Also having problem with translating the articles, I want to use a proprietary machine-translating algorithm, one mine, but I don't know how to build one.
I am having problem hosting the website in Heroku ou Netfily, because they don't give permissions to pyttsx3 since it uses windows voices. Also I would like to have words streaming at least 20 words streaming, like apps for dynamic reading or edge browser.
